# Updating datagrid size after dropping a new component into it

Tags: jsf-2, xhtml, primefaces

i'm writing a drag and drop components the user can drag a simple panel wich dropped into a dataGrid , my problem is when i drop a new panel the datagrid didn't change size dynamically. 
So is there an attribute to be set or something else .
here's the example i followed http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dndGrid.jsf
Thank you in advance .

and here's my code :

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">   
 <p:column>
    <p:fieldset id="belongTo" legend="Belong To" >  
     <p:dataGrid id="userGroups"
              var="userGroup"
              value="#{projectAdminisrationMB.selectedUserMemberOfGroups}"
              columns="3">  
    <p:column>  
      <p:panel id="pnl1"
               header="#{userGroup.name}"
               style="text-align:center">
        <h:panelGrid columns="1" style="width:100%">  
          <p:graphicImage value="/images/group/adminGroup.gif"/> 
        </h:panelGrid>  
      </p:panel>  
      <p:draggable for="pnl1"
                   revert="true"
                   handle=".ui-panel-titlebar"
                   stack=".ui-panel"/>
    </p:column>  
  </p:dataGrid>  
</p:fieldset>  
<p:droppable for="belongTo"
             tolerance="touch"
             activeStyleClass="ui-state-highlight"
             datasource="userNotGroups" >
  <p:ajax listener="#{projectAdminisrationMB.onExcludeFromGroupDrop}" />
 </p:droppable> 
 </p:column>
 <p:column>  
   <p:fieldset id="excludeFrom"
            legend="Exclude From"
            style="margin-top:20px">  
  <p:dataGrid id="userNotGroups"
              var="userNotGroup"
              value="#{projectAdminisrationMB.selectedUserNotMemberOfGroups}"
              columns="3">  
    <p:column>  
      <p:panel id="pnl2"
               header="#{userNotGroup.name}"
               style="text-align:center">  
        <h:panelGrid columns="1" style="width:100%">  
          <p:graphicImage value="/images/grou/defaultGroup.gif"/> 
        </h:panelGrid>  
      </p:panel>  
      <p:draggable for="pnl2"
                   revert="true"
                   handle=".ui-panel-titlebar" 
                   stack=".ui-panel"/>  
    </p:column>  
  </p:dataGrid>  
</p:fieldset>   
<p:droppable for="excludeFrom"
             tolerance="touch"
             activeStyleClass="ui-state-highlight"
             datasource="userGroups"  >  
  <p:ajax listener="#{projectAdminisrationMB.onBelongToGroupDrop}"  />  
  </p:droppable>  
  </p:column>
</h:panelGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the "update" parameter to your two p:ajax calls.

```
<p:ajax listener="#{projectAdminisrationMB.onExcludeFromGroupDrop}" update="userNotGroups userGroups" />

<p:ajax listener="#{projectAdminisrationMB.onBelongToGroupDrop}"  update="userNotGroups userGroups"  />
```

The link you referenced is using this technique. The update parameter takes the ids of the components you want to update. [PrimeFaces DnD Demo](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/dndGrid.jsf)

Hope this helps.